# I need to use numpy's vectorization to optimize my double for loop

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, numpy

I have a python function with a nested for loop that is called thousands of times, and is too slow. From what I have read online, there should be a way to optimize it with numpy vectorization so that the iteration is done in much faster C code rather than python. But, I have never worked with numpy before and I can't figure it out.

The function is ：First slice from the first row, then calculate the sum of s column 1 row from the back to the front, if it is greater than or equal to n, return the total number; then slice from the first two rows, then calculate the sum of s column 1 row from the back to the front, if it is less than n, then calculate the sum of s column 2 rows, if it is greater than or equal to n, return the number of rows; and so on, until all the rows are cycled.

The original code (python 3.8) is:

```
import pandas as pd
from time import time
import numpy as np

def sumbars(df, s, n):
    start = time()
    df2 = df[s].copy()
    # df2.loc[0]=1000
    df['sumbars'] = 0
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df3 = df2[:i + 1]
        l = len(df3)
        for j in range(l):
            # if i>=8:
            #     print()
            df4 = df3[l - j - 1:]
            if df4.sum() >= n:
                df.loc[i, 'sumbars'] = j + 1
                # df5=df[['trade_date',s,'sumbars']]
                break

    stop = time()
    global sumbarstime
    sumbarstime = sumbarstime + stop - start
    return df['sumbars']

def main():
    # df=pd.read_csv('todo.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ts_code':['IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX'],'jc':[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]})
    df['jcts2'] = sumbars(df,'jc',2)

    
    print('')
    df.to_csv("result.csv",index=False,sep=',')

    # print sec

    return

main()
```

I need to optimize the double for loop is:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
        df3 = df2[:i + 1]
        l = len(df3)
        for j in range(l):
            # if i>=8:
            #     print()
            df4 = df3[l - j - 1:]
            if df4.sum() >= n:
                df.loc[i, 'sumbars'] = j + 1
                # df5=df[['trade_date',s,'sumbars']]
                break
```

Someone helps me optimized my code once, and I need to optimize the last for loop once.
After optimizing a for loop ：

```
import pandas as pd
from time import time
import numpy as np


def sumbars(df, s, n, ):
    start = time()
    sdata = np.array(df[s])
    sdata = np.flipud(sdata)
    l = len(sdata)
    sumbars = np.zeros(l)
    for i in range(l):
        n1 = sdata[i:]
        cumsum = np.cumsum(n1)
        k = np.argmax(cumsum >= n)
        n2 = cumsum[k]
        if (k != 0) | ((n2 != 0) & (n == 1)):
            sumbars[l - i - 1] = k + 1
    sumbars = sumbars.astype(int)
    df['sumbars'] = sumbars
    stop = time()
    global sumbarstime
    sumbarstime += stop - start
    # df.to_csv("my.csv")
    # print(df['sumbars'])
    return df['sumbars']

def main():
    # df=pd.read_csv('todo.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ts_code':['IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX','IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX', 'IC2103.CFX'],'jc':[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]})
    df['jcts2'] = sumbars(df,'jc',2)

    
    print('')
    df.to_csv("result.csv",index=False,sep=',')

    # print sec

    return

main()
```

Help: I need to optimize the last for loop with numpy vectorization. Besides using cumsum, is there any other way to optimize my original double for loop?

```
    for i in range(l):
        n1 = sdata[i:]
        cumsum = np.cumsum(n1)
        k = np.argmax(cumsum >= n)
        n2 = cumsum[k]
        if (k != 0) | ((n2 != 0) & (n == 1)):
            sumbars[l - i - 1] = k + 1
```

Please give me more time to reply after pointing out my problems.

Comment: Not every calculation is "vectorizable".  `numpy` vectorizing means using compiled numpy methods.  Most of those methods are "parallel" in nature, operating on the whole array without any implied order or sequence (though the `c` code will iterate).  `np.cumsum` is an exception, a function that is sequential in nature.  Your use  of `cumsum` suggests the problem is sequential in nature, and may require thinking-outside-the-box to "vectorize" (if that is possible).

Comment: I added the original code. Besides using cumsum, is there any other way to optimize my double for loop?

Comment: You can always try the [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) library, that is supposed to work well with numpy functions.

Comment: Are the input values of `df[s]` always positives?

Comment: The input values of df[s] are always positives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the **input values of `df[s]` are always positives**, you can significantly **improve the algorithm**. Indeed, the complexity of your current implementation is **`O(n**2)`** while in this case, it is possible to write an algorithm with the complexity **`O(n log n)`** (and probably even `O(n)`).

The improved solution consist in computing the `cumsum` only once and perform incremental updates.
Indeed, it is not needed to recompute it since `np.cumsum(arr[i:])` is always equal to `fullCumsum[i:]-m` with `fullCumsum = np.cumsum(arr)` and `m = np.sum(arr[:i])`.
`fullCumsum` is independent of `i` so it can be precomputed.
`m` can be computed incrementally in the loop.
`k` can be found using a binary search since values are sorted.

Here is the resulting (pure Python) implementation:

```py
def sumbarsFast(df, s, n, ):
    sdata = np.array(df[s])
    sdata = np.flipud(sdata)
    l = len(sdata)
    sumbars = np.zeros(l)
    fullCumsum = np.cumsum(sdata)
    m = 0
    for i in range(l):
        k = np.searchsorted(fullCumsum[i:], n + m)
        if k == len(fullCumsum)-i:
            k = 0
        if (k != 0) or ((fullCumsum[i+k] != m) and (n == 1)):
            sumbars[l - i - 1] = k + 1
        m += sdata[i]
    sumbars = sumbars.astype(int)
    df['sumbars'] = sumbars
    return df['sumbars']
```

It is possible to be even much faster using the **Numba JIT and parallelism**:

```py
from numba import njit, prange, int64

@njit(int64[:](int64[:], int64), parallel=True)
def sumbarsKernel(sdata, n):
    l = len(sdata)
    fullCumsum = np.cumsum(sdata)
    sumbars = np.zeros(l, dtype=np.int64)
    nShared = np.int64(n)
    for i in prange(l):
        m = fullCumsum[i-1] if i > 0 else 0
        k = np.searchsorted(fullCumsum[i:], n + m)
        if k == len(fullCumsum)-i:
            k = 0
        if (k != 0) or ((fullCumsum[i+k] != m) and (nShared == 1)):
            sumbars[l - i - 1] = k + 1
    return sumbars

def sumbarsSuperFast(df, s, n, ):
    sdata = np.array(df[s], dtype=np.int64)
    sdata = np.flipud(sdata)
    sumbars = sumbarsKernel(sdata, n)
    sumbars = sumbars.astype(int)
    df['sumbars'] = sumbars
    return df['sumbars']
```

Here are timings with a dataframe containing 200000 lines on my machine:

```
Your naive version:         589.764 seconds
Your "optimized" version:   121.683 seconds
sumbarsFast (pure Python):    1.081 second
sumbarsSuperFast (Numba):     0.004 second
```

The final implementation is about **150000 times faster** than your naive version and **30000 times faster** than your "optimized" version.

Comment: It seems that the effect is super good, I am going to debug the code now.

Comment: If I use my dataframe that I posted, I commented out the line of JIT and the sumbarsSuperFast's result is correct. If it is not commented, the result is wrong. Why is that?

Comment: Indeed, the problem comes from parallelism in the Numba code. It looks like a *bug in Numba* or a *limitation of `prange`* (related to Python objects)... I fixed this issue by copying explicitly the Python integer `n` into a safe shared `np.int64` variable. Results are now the same between all implementations and the performance is still the same :) .